# Virtual Interface in Config class

Tags: system-verilog, uvm, test-bench

How do I point out an interface in TB_top from my configuration class using virtual interface without using uvm_config_db?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid the _right way_ of doing things?

Comment: Just an interview question I heard from someone.

Comment: Not getting the question. Your interface is in configuration class and you want to assign the virtual interface to that interface in top module. Is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question tests your knowledge of `uvm_config_db`, which is just a database of global variables inside the uvm_pkg. All your have to do is create a virtual interface variable inside the package where you define your configuration class, then set it before calling `run_test()`

```
package my_config_pkg;

virtual my_interface vif;
class my_configuration;
...
endclass
endpackage



module TB_top;

my_interface ifinst();

initial begin
        my_config_pkg::vif = ifinst;
        run_test("my_test");
end
endmodule
```